# Error during installation :'msiexec.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I am trying to  install a software on Win 7 but the installation fails giving this error:

```
There has been an error. 
Error Running C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack/pythonPackages/installpython.bat:   
'msiexec.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
The application will now exit.
```

However the same installation is successful on another device with similar OS.

How do I rectify this ?

**EDIT :**

**As figured out from the below discussion with @Diogo_Rocha, the problem may be due to having a 64 bit CPU but with 32 bit Windows 7 installed on it.**

**But I still haven't found a way to recify this issue since I am not in a position to re-install WIN 7 X64 after performing a complete wipe up on my computer**

Comment: Could you please check what happens when you do the following: Click the Start button and enter into the field *Search programs and files* the command `cmd.exe`, then press Enter. When the black windows appears, please enter `msiexec.exe` and press Return again. Does a new window open or does it throw the same error message as with the batch at you?

Comment: @TeX HeX : Thanks.. I tried it out but I get the very same error message

Comment: Actually there is an issue that might be probably affecting this which I figured out from the discussion with @Diogo_Rocha below. I have a 64 bit CPU but 32 bit Windows 7 is installed on it.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, there is no 32 / 64-bit problem.

Maybe the problem is as simple as that Windows can not find MSIEXEC.exe

Could you please open a command prompt and enter `SET PATH`. There will be a long list of directories, separated by `;`. Can you please verify that the directory *C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32* is included in this list?

You might need to copy the entire output to Notepad to line up all folders and verify that ...\System32 is in the list.

Comment: I get this message `Windows cannot find 'c:\Windows\SysWoW64\cmd.exe' Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.`

Comment: Okay, then let us verify this: Click Start, enter `system` and then click `System Information` in the Programs list. Inside the appearing program, what does it say for the entry *System Type*? If it says "x64" than you have a 64-bit Windows version.

Comment: It says `System Type: X86-based PC
`

Comment: `Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5000+, 2600 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)`

Comment: Could you figure out where is the fault ?

Comment: Okay, then we have a complete different error here. When you execute this on the PC that is working, does is also say `X86-based PC` or something different?

Comment: (if you're talking about the PC where the installation was succesful), yes that PC also says `x86 based PC`

Comment: Yes, that's the PC that I wanted to know about. This means, we are having a complete different problem here and no 32/64-bit issue. Let me update the answer, I have another idea.

Comment: `C:\Users\Marcos>SET PATH`

`Path=C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin`

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

`C:\Users\Marcos>`

Comment: Above is the output I am getting on entering `SET PATH`. I cannot see the directory that you're talking about

Comment: How do I include the directory you're talking about\

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue... !! Thank you very very much for your time and help :)

Comment: Your welcome and good to hear it is solved now.